# Can't connect adminer to postgres server in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, adminer

I'm trying to run latest version of PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) using docker-compose

```
# Use postgres/pswd user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pswd
      POSTGRES_DB: auth_db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Start container

```
docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 3/3
 - Network postgres-docker_default Created 0.0s
 - Container postgres-docker-adminer-1  Started 0.8s
 - Container postgres-docker-db-1       Started 1.1s
```

on attempt to connect to database from adminer (http://localhost:8080/) I've got Error

```
Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

[image]

- then I try to edit `postgresql.conf` file on my mapped volume by uncommenting line `port = 5432   # (change requires restart)`
- restart container

  - confirm that `postgresql.conf` in docker file system have uncommented line `port = 5432 # (change requires restart)`
- still have same error
- logs in `postgres-docker-db-1` shows that server is running...

```
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.498 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.498 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.498 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.506 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.538 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-23 23:03:37 UTC
2023-03-23 19:03:44 2023-03-23 23:03:44.586 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-03-23 19:03:44
2023-03-23 19:03:44 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Please give me an idea how I can connect to postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using `localhost`, there are different types of [network solutions](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) in Docker. The default one is bridge network, you only need to use `db:5432` (the service name from `docker-compose.yml`) instead of `localhost:5432`.

Tested for you :)

Comment: What exactly I can add to my docker-compose to be able connect to localhost?

Comment: For mac and windows you an use `host.docker.internal:5432` to access the main machine (host) with default bridge networking. I couldn't test because mac, but you can use host networking, in host networking you don't need to publish ports, there is no isolation. You can just use the ports of the apps, like `localhost:5432`

Comment: So "ports: - 5432:5432" in compose file not required?

Comment: Only for host networking type, for the bridge they're required.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
localhost:5432 
# should be remplace by 
db


#    ports:
#      - 5432:5432
# This is only required if you use the ip of docker

# should be remplace by 
192.168.1.10
```

adminer container don't have database on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however, the cause was that I had installed postgresql on my windows machine months ago.

When I started a postgresql container in docker, I had problems accessing localhost with my user and password configured in docker-compose.

Nevertheless, make sure you don't have already a postgres running locally by mistake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).